# App crashes when using JSON-Framework

Tags: iphone, json, crash, polling

Here is the code I am using to create poll data from a json framework.  However every time I launch the app it crashes.  Any Advice?

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;

    NSArray *latestEvent = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"Events"];
    [responseString release];

    //Choose event
    NSDictionary *flashMob = [latestEvent objectAtIndex:0];

    //Fetch the Data
    NSString *name = [flashMob objectForKey:@"event"];
    NSDate *eDate = [flashMob objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *location = [flashMob objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString *danceVid = [flashMob objectForKey:@"dancevideo"];

    //Set the text to the label
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Next Flash Mob is: %@, on %@, near %@, with Dance: %@", name, eDate, location, danceVid];

}
```

And the Json is:

```
{ "Events":[{"id":0001,"event":"Party Rock Anthem Flash Mob","date":"12/18/2011",
"dancevideo":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dP2ddTuMKIg","Location":"Flatirons Crossing,       Broomfield, CO"}]
}
```

Edit I am also including the viewDidLoad method unless the call might be failing.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.corliosity.com/denverflash.json"]];
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    }
```

Comment: What error message does it throw?

Comment: And what line does it error on?

Comment: There is no error message just a crash.

Comment: I get 'sharedlibrary-apply-load-rules all'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // try this code here
    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [[[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease] objectWithData:responseData];
    [self.responseData release] // only if is retained by your class.
    self.resposeDate = nil;

    NSArray *latestEvent = [JSONDictionary valueForKey:@"Events"];
    [responseString release];

    //Choose event
    NSDictionary *flashMob = [latestEvent objectAtIndex:0];

    //Fetch the Data
    NSString *name = [flashMob objectForKey:@"event"];
    NSDate *eDate = [flashMob objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *location = [flashMob objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString *danceVid = [flashMob objectForKey:@"dancevideo"];

    //Set the text to the label
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Next Flash Mob is: %@, on %@, near %@, with Dance: %@", name, eDate, location, danceVid];
}
```

Now you should see Events key inside JSONDictionary, the corresponding object should be an array of dictionary.
Process it in the way you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, but my app will still crash.  the only thing is see in the editor is `sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all` and in the following line `Current language: auto, currently objective-c`

Answer (score 0):

Check the didReceiveResponse callback and parse the headers and error code.

I don't see any issue in the JSON.But check the JSON format by using the eval method of javascript.

When I tried to validate this JSON string using [online json validator](http://jsonlint.com/) I could see one error.

Comment: What would I look for in the didRecieveResponse?

Comment: I suggest this other website for online JSON human readable view. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ copy and past your JSON to verify it and read it in the viewer tab.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your JSON string through a validator, http://jsonlint.com and it doesn't work. It is expecting a string for your ID and it is getting a number. I would check where you are getting your data from, maybe it is as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks there was a problem with the id value but it still crashes.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the broken JSON (if you change the "id" value from `0001` into `1` or `"0001"` it works) I think your fundamental problem is these two lines:

```
NSDate *eDate = [flashMob objectForKey:@"date"];
NSString *location = [flashMob objectForKey:@"location"];
```

You're assigning an NSString to a pointer of type NSDate. (There is no automatic conversion of NSString to NSDate, even if it looks like a date.) This is most likely your main problem.

Secondly, your `location` variable will be `nil` because your data has the key `Location` but your code uses `location` with a lower-case "L".